# list of macro variables to dataset in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a macro variable as the below

```
%let myGrp = ('ctry', 'age')
```

all i want to do is create a dataset called `TestGrp` which has the below

```
GROUPS
ctry
age
```

I am unable to figure out how to do this. Any help is much appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SCAN` is the function that will help you the most here.  Odds are your entire approach could be improved, but given this to start with...

```
%let myGrp = ('ctry', 'age');
data yourdata;
do _t = 1 to countc("&mygrp",",")+1;
  groups = scan("&myGrp",_t,"'(,) ");
  output;
end;
run;
```

`SCAN` takes any number of delimiters, and can be useful here to remove characters you do not want.  In the long run, `%let mygrp=ctry,age;` would be just as well - the quotes etc. aren't helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much, makes sense I will drop the quotes.. If i want to just extract the first variable "ctry" from mygrp should i just use scan as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example (sorry for the Spanish names):

```
%let sListaDeValoresAutorizados= ('ctry', 'age');
%LET LISTA_VALORES = %UNQUOTE(%sysfunc(compress("&sListaDeValoresAutorizados","(')")));

DATA yourdata;
    %DO _t = 1 %TO %sysfunc(countw("&LISTA_VALORES",','));
        GROUPS = strip(scan("&LISTA_VALORES",&_t,","));
        OUTPUT;
    %END;
RUN;
```